# How do i refresh the page in Jquery when the dialog Modal is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some set of values updated in the modal and the modal is opened on the same page .
on closing the Modal How can i refresh the Page in jquery

```
$("#dialog-modal").bind('dialogclose',function() {
  //How Do i refresh the current Page.
)};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`window.location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#reload):

```
$("#dialog-modal").bind('dialogclose',function(){
    // force the browser to get the page from the server
    window.location.reload(true);
)}
```

---

**Edit:**

It would appear the OP was looking for this as the answer (from comments, below):

```
$("#dialog-modal").bind('dialogclose',function(){
    $('#someForm').submit();
)}
```

Comment: will eat you:when i say above line it is showing white screen in IE and it is saying with dialog  "The PAgE cannot be refreshed until without resending the information ciick retry to send the information again" How can i avoid that dialog and just refreshing

Comment: You're having the user arrive at this page by a POST. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: @Here: if you don't mind, use the Twitter-style "@username" so that the person you're addressing gets notified of your response. I was fairly confused by your comment...

Comment: @Someone: then don't try and reload the page. Use jQuery to select the form and then submit it, like this: `$('#someForm').submit();`

Answer (score 5):

```
window.location.reload(true);
```